# To understand a line of PHP code about a connection

Tags: php, connection

**What is connection() in the following code?**

*Code which I do understand completely*

```
if($user->connection($email,$password)){
}
```

---

Let's assume `connection()` is pseudo-code.
**Is the `pg_prepare` and pg_execute` enough to create the connection?**

---

The line caused me to omit the use of its main code in [generating a login system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266569/to-improve-login-code-in-php-by-sessions). Subsequently, SOers pointed out severe sequrity holes in my code.

I could not find the explanation for the function `connection()`.
The code seems to be pseudo-code to me, since the connection does not have any attributes to the database, for instance by

**Example of how the connection should be formed**

```
     $result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "query22", "SELECT passhash_md5 FROM users
         WHERE email=$1;");                                             
     $passhash_md5 = pg_execute($dbconn, "query22", array($_REQUEST['email']));
```

Comment: Ummm. Your question makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$user is an instance of a class.

connection is a method in that class.

$mail & $password are parameters to that method.

This has nothing todo with arrays. what you mean would be:

```
$foo = array("key" => "value");
```

maybe this can help you:
http://www.webstockbox.com/php/7-tutorials-on-how-to-create-a-php-login-system/

Answer (score 2):

I haven't actually used php.net, but this just looks like connection is a method of object $user that takes 2 params.  Nothing to do with arrays.

Comment: This is exactly what that line says.

Comment: sorry masi, reading your questions really suggest you should read some very very basic coding beginners guids.

Comment: I am newbie in PHP, but not in Programming. - PHP's objects seem to be like in Java: http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php